# Declare many angular services using some sort of 'umbrella' service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have too many services to be included in my angular dependence lists and I am willing to somehow create an 'umbrella' service.

The goal is to declare this service for a dependency and have bunch of other services declared.

What would be the optimal way to do it in code, if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just inject all the dependant service into the umberlla service which you want to create like below.

**Using umberlla service:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, umb) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  console.log(umb.serv1.obj);
  console.log(umb.serv2.obj);
});
```

**common services:**

```
app.service('serv1', function() {
  var me =this;
  me.obj ='Im from service 1';
  return me;
});

app.service('serv2', function() {
  var me =this;
  me.obj ='Im from service 2';
  return me;
});
```

**Umberlla service:**
app.service('umb', function(serv1, serv2) {

```
  var me = this;
  me.serv1 = serv1; 
  me.serv2 = serv2;
  return this;
});
```

**Sample Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/MIZTYdz4OsuR0S89n5kG?p=preview